# How to make an array of this string?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string like this:

```
$str = '"list":["test 1","test 2"]';
```

How to make an array:

```
$arr['list'] = array('test 1','test 2');
```

?

Comment: missed quotes. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make it a valid JSON string and use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function like this:

```
$str = '"list":["test 1","test 2"]';
$arr = json_decode('{' . $str . '}', true);
print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [list] => Array
        (
            [0] => test 1
            [1] => test 2
        )
)
```